# NullPointerException when trying to read an RDF file using Jena elephas's TriplesInputFormat in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdf, jena

I tried to load an RDF file into a Spark RDD using the Apache Jena Elephas. The RDF file is of the Turtle format. The code is as follows.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.jena.hadoop.rdf.io.input.TriplesInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.jena.hadoop.rdf.types.TripleWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

object RDFTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("RDFTest")
      .setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val hadoopConf = new Configuration()

    val rdfTriples = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
        "file:///media/xinwang/Elements/data/chembl/20.0-uncompressed/cco.ttl", 
        classOf[TriplesInputFormat],
        classOf[LongWritable],
        classOf[TripleWritable],
        hadoopConf)

    rdfTriples.take(10).foreach(println)

  }

}
```

However, when I ran the program, it threw a NullPointerException. The log info of running the program is as follows.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/11/21 11:58:33 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.2
15/11/21 11:58:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/11/21 11:58:33 WARN Utils: Your hostname, x1 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.7 instead (on interface wlan0)
15/11/21 11:58:33 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/11/21 11:58:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: xinwang
15/11/21 11:58:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: xinwang
15/11/21 11:58:33 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(xinwang); users with modify permissions: Set(xinwang)
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.0.7:45252]
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 45252.
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-1bc925bc-9bc4-45d2-a67a-00b6d9790d85
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 919.9 MB
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-3a0e0453-af83-4fab-bf33-457d6e5932c7/httpd-047c004d-435f-474f-906c-78ee07e2ae2d
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 39793.
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/11/21 11:58:34 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
15/11/21 11:58:34 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4042.
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.0.7:4042
15/11/21 11:58:34 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
15/11/21 11:58:34 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 45670.
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 45670
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:45670 with 919.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 45670)
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(130896) called with curMem=0, maxMem=964574576
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 127.8 KB, free 919.8 MB)
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(14349) called with curMem=130896, maxMem=964574576
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 14.0 KB, free 919.8 MB)
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:45670 (size: 14.0 KB, free: 919.9 MB)
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from newAPIHadoopFile at RDFTest.scala:22
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/11/21 11:58:35 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at RDFTest.scala:29
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (take at RDFTest.scala:29) with 1 output partitions
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(take at RDFTest.scala:29)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (file:///media/xinwang/Elements/data/chembl/20.0-uncompressed/cco.ttl NewHadoopRDD[0] at newAPIHadoopFile at RDFTest.scala:22), which has no missing parents
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1880) called with curMem=145245, maxMem=964574576
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1880.0 B, free 919.7 MB)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1150) called with curMem=147125, maxMem=964574576
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1150.0 B, free 919.7 MB)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:45670 (size: 1150.0 B, free: 919.9 MB)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (file:///media/xinwang/Elements/data/chembl/20.0-uncompressed/cco.ttl NewHadoopRDD[0] at newAPIHadoopFile at RDFTest.scala:22)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2207 bytes)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO NewHadoopRDD: Input split: file:/media/xinwang/Elements/data/chembl/20.0-uncompressed/cco.ttl:0+61178
15/11/21 11:58:36 WARN AbstractLineBasedNodeTupleReader: Configured to ignore bad tuples, parsing errors will be logged and further parsing aborted but no user visible errors will be thrown.  Consider setting rdf.io.input.ignore-bad-tuples to false to disable this behaviour
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO AbstractLineBasedNodeTupleReader: Got split with start 0 and length 61178 for file with total length of 61178
15/11/21 11:58:36 ERROR AbstractLineBasedNodeTupleReader: Error parsing whole file, aborting further parsing
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.directivePrefix(LangTurtleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.directive(LangTurtleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:78)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:175)
    at org.apache.jena.hadoop.rdf.io.input.readers.AbstractWholeFileNodeTupleReader$1.run(AbstractWholeFileNodeTupleReader.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 2040 bytes result sent to driver
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 594 ms on localhost (1/1)
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (take at RDFTest.scala:29) finished in 0.605 s
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: take at RDFTest.scala:29, took 0.660084 s
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.0.7:4042
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
15/11/21 11:58:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3a0e0453-af83-4fab-bf33-457d6e5932c7
```

When I tried to debug, it showed that at `org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.directivePrefix(LangTurtleBase.java:162)` the calling to the `getPrefixMap()` method returned a null pointer.

[Screenshot of the location where the NullPointerException is thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiZCi.png)

Then I found in the Jena source code when the `Prologue` object is created at `RdfIOUtils.createParserProfile(JobContext, Path) line: 60` in the initialization stage, it passes `null` as the first argument of the constructor.

[null passed to the Prologue class constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKnpw.png)

And in the Prologue's constructor the argument `pmap` whose value is `null` is just assigned to `this.prefixMap`.

`org.apache.jena.riot.Prologue.java line: 54`

```
public Prologue(PrefixMap pmap, IRIResolver resolver)
{
    this.prefixMap = pmap ; 
    this.resolver = resolver ;
}
```

I think this is probably the reason why the `getPrefixMap()` method returned a null pointer.

But I'm just wondering how to solve this problem.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Elephas which has been filed as [JENA-1075](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1075) and has now been fixed

The bug only affects Turtle inputs so you can avoid this by converting your input data to formats other than Turtle.

Alternatively you can point your Maven build to use the latest development snapshots (`3.0.1-SNAPSHOT` at the time of writing) which will pull down a version which includes the fix

Comment: Thanks @RobV. I did exactly what you have changed in RdfIOUtils.java as `JENA-1075` in my cloned Jena repository, and made a Maven install and used the `3.0.1-SNAPSHOT` dependency. The Turtle RDF file has been input successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the TriplesInputFormat with the TurtleInputFormat which is in the package org.apache.jena.hadoop.rdf.io.input.turtle. Hoping this helps.